# Twig include performance with and without passing variables

Tags: php, performance, symfony, twig

I am wondering what is best perfomance-wise, using

```
{% include "_inc/template" %}
```

or

```
{% include "_inc/template" with {'foo': bar %}
```

assuming `foo` is the only variable used in `_inc/template` and it's also available in global context.

Will there be significant difference in performance between two approaches, if the `include` is placed within `for` having ~50 loops?

Comment: variables should be passed by references, so it shoudln't be that big of an impact

Comment: Useless micro optimization. I think the "only" option allows you to be sure not to get wrong variables from the parent context. Passing variables is usefull when renaming like `'form' => 'context_form'` and for readability of course. So you know the mandatory parameters that your include is using.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have direct answer to your question, but you can use the profiler in dev toolbar to see the timeline of the calls.

Maybe try and tell us...

Which is the version of symfony you use?
I know that in symfony > 2.7 the timeline Graph exist.

Ps : Maybe try it with this too:

```
{% include 'template.html' with {'foo': 'bar'} only %}
```